# OpenProcess() succeeds, but EnumProcessModules() fails

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code executing in a Windows Service
on Windows XP 32-bit:

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                       FALSE,
                       a_impl->pid);

if (0 == h)
{
    throw Process_exception(__LINE__,
                            __FILE__,
                            "Failed obtain module list for '" +
                                a_impl->exe_name + "'",
                            GetLastError());
}

DWORD required_size  = 1024 * sizeof(HMODULE);
DWORD module_entries = 0;
BOOL result;
DWORD last_error;
HMODULE* module_handles = 0;

do
{
    module_entries = required_size / sizeof(HMODULE);
    delete[] module_handles;
    module_handles = new HMODULE[module_entries];
    memset(module_handles, 0, sizeof(HMODULE) * module_entries);

    result = EnumProcessModules(h,
                                module_handles, 
                                sizeof(HMODULE) * module_entries,
                                &required_size);

    last_error = GetLastError();

} while (TRUE == result &&
         required_size > (sizeof(HMODULE) * module_entries));

if (FALSE == result)
{
    CloseHandle(h);
    delete[] module_handles;

    throw Process_exception(__LINE__,
                            __FILE__,
                            "Failed to enumerate module list for '" +
                                a_impl->exe_name + "'",
                            last_error);
}
```

The Windows Service is deployed on many machines and on some machines
(which I do not have access to)
the `EnumProcessModules()` call fails with `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`.
This fails, to the best of my knowledge, while querying a process
started by the logged on user: I have been unable to reproduce this
and tried the following:

- Using Process Explorer, denied the local system account read memory
  and write memory access to a process started by the logged on the user.
- Starting a process in a different session (Windows Services and processes
  started by the first logged on user execute in the same session, `0`)

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

*Note, the only process which I have seen this behaviour is the System process
(typically process id 4).*

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx) contains the answer:

> If this function is called from a 32-bit application running on WOW64, it can only enumerate the modules of a 32-bit process. If the process is a 64-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is **ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY** (299).

The machines on which this error code is returned are 64 bit systems and the process whose modules you are enumerating is a 64 bit process.

<strike>To enumerate the modules of a 64 bit process from your 32 bit service you need to use [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633.aspx).</strike> In fact it looks like you may need to run a 64 bit process in order to enumerate process modules.

**Update**: You are apparently sure that the the systems on which the code is failing are 32 bit systems. In that case perhaps the failures are when you try to enumerate modules of 16 bit processes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that it is 32-bit XP platform.

Comment: OK, but the machines that you don't have access to will be 64 bit.

Comment: By don't have access to I mean me personally: I can't go and login and have a look. Data is collected from these machines remotely, including architecture and Windows platform plus any failure messages.

Comment: Good thought on 16-bit process, but I thought 16-bit processes run as a single thread within NTVDM.exe on XP?

Comment: "_To enumerate the modules of a 64 bit process from your 32 bit service_".  I don't think you can even with `EnumProcessModulesEx`.  Documentation states: "_This function is intended primarily for 64-bit applications. If the function is called by a 32-bit application running under WOW64, the dwFilterFlag option is ignored and the function provides the same results as the EnumProcessModules function._"

Answer (score 2):

Reason might be because You are using CreateProcessA in your code.. and suddenly calling EnumProcessModules.Thus windows is not able to create ModuleInfo by that time.And it returns error 299(Thinking its a 64 bit system.. as it fails to read the memory).

Please look here for a solution
[EnumProcessModules failed with error 299 on 32bit win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767093/enumprocessmodules-failed-with-error-299-on-32bit-win7)