# EnumProcessModules failed with error 299 on 32bit win7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

My code is running on win7 32bit, but when I use `EnumProcessModules`, it returned false and getlasterror() return  error code 299, which declare that the program is 32bit and this statement can not be running on 64bit system.

I wonder why this happens, and why the system thinks that I am running on a 64bit OS?

The code I use:

```
         HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPid);
         if (hProcess)
         {
            HMODULE hMod = NULL;
            DWORD cbNeeded = 0;
            if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
            {
              //do something here...
            }
         }
```

dwPid is the id of the process I want to manipulate.

PS.This error just happen on one of my test machine, others are fine. So This problem may be related to that specific machine or system configration?

Comment: Your title says `EnumProcessModulesEx`, and the body says `EnumProcessModules`. Which is it? Both of those return `BOOL`, so I'm not sure what "returned with error code 299" means, either. Do you mean "After it fails, GetLastError returns 299"? Please [edit] your question to include your code and to be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Well, you got half. Thanks. :-) Once again, please include your code. It's very difficult to say what might be wrong if we can't see what you're doing in the first place.

Comment: I feel like I'm pulling teeth here. :-) There's no call to `GetLastError` in the code you posted, so there's no way you got a 'error 299' with this code , which means it's not the actual code you're using (or your question is made up in the first place). If you want help, **post your code** so we can help.

Comment: This is really my code here, the version which has GetLastError in it is the one I use to locate the error. The code is as simple as it looks, and that's why I'm confused. This error just happen on one of my test machine, others are fine.

Comment: From MSDN: If this function is called from a 32-bit application running on WOW64, it can only enumerate the modules of a 32-bit process. If the process is a 64-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And that's the interesting part: that test machine is 32bit win7, and I'm sure about that.

Comment: Are there any 16-bit processes running around?

Comment: Run Taskmgr.exe on that machine and select the Processes tab.  Do you see any processes that have an * asterisk after their name?

Comment: no, I dont' see any * in processes tab

Comment: Still not find the reason, but I use another way to accomplish what I want.Thanks for your helps anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Though It has been a while since you posted this question.But I thought of giving it a try .

Reason might be because You are using CreateProcessA in your code.. and suddenly calling EnumProcessModules.Thus windows is not able to create ModuleInfo by that time.And it returns error 299(Thinking its a 64 bit system.. as it fails to read the memory).

Actually I was stuck at this too  and  figured it out..after looking at your post.
Thanks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx
CreatProcess Remarks.. It ask to call WaitforInput Idle before proceeding.;-)

The calling thread can use the WaitForInputIdle function to wait until the new process has finished its initialization and is waiting for user input with no input pending. This can be useful for synchronization between parent and child processes, because CreateProcess returns without waiting for the new process to finish its initialization. For example, the creating process would use WaitForInputIdle before trying to find a window associated with the new process.